# How to create a project from github template with custom package name?

Tags: android, android-studio, plugins

When I use template from https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-platform-plugin-template#sample-code it creates as
`/my-account-name/new-project-name` (renamed automatically).

My task: create multi module template for my company (for reusing).
I created template with

> package com.companyname.templatename

And when I tried to use that template it was created as `com.companyname.templatename`, but i want `com.companyname.newprojectname`

Seems, that for **auto** package renaming template files should use

> package com.myaccountname.templatename

But its not good for me, cause I wanna use *company-name* as vendor.

Do you know any ways to **auto** renaming a template's package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought that their auto-renaming works cause they used the correct vendors name, but in their code I found .yml file with solution

```
name: Template Cleanup
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:

  # Run cleaning process only if workflow is triggered by the template repository.
  template-cleanup:
    name: Template Cleanup
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: write
    if: github.event.repository.name != 'android-template'
    steps:

      # Check out current repository
      - name: Fetch Sources
        uses: actions/checkout@v3

      # Cleanup project
      - name: Cleanup
        run: |
          export LC_CTYPE=C
          export LANG=C

          # Prepare variables
          NAME="${GITHUB_REPOSITORY##*/}"
          SAFE_NAME=$(echo $NAME | sed 's/[^a-zA-Z0-9]//g' | tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]')
          GROUP="com.companyname.$SAFE_NAME"

          # Replace placeholders in the template-cleanup files
          sed -i "s/%NAME%/$NAME/g" .github/template-cleanup/*
          sed -i "s/%REPOSITORY%/${GITHUB_REPOSITORY/\//\\/}/g" .github/template-cleanup/*
          sed -i "s/%GROUP%/$GROUP/g" .github/template-cleanup/*

          # Replace template package name in project files with $GROUP
          find app/src -type f -exec sed -i "s/com.companyname.template/$GROUP/g" {} +
          find app/src -type f -exec sed -i "s/Template/$NAME/g" {} +

          # Move content
          mkdir -p app/src/main/java/${GROUP//.//}
          mkdir -p app/src/test/java/${GROUP//.//}
          cp -R .github/template-cleanup/* .
          cp -R app/src/main/java/com/companyname/template/* app/src/main/java/${GROUP//.//}/
          cp -R app/src/test/java/com/companyname/template/* app/src/test/java/${GROUP//.//}/

          # Cleanup
          rm -rf \
            .github/ISSUE_TEMPLATE \
            .github/readme \
            .github/template-cleanup \
            .github/workflows/template-cleanup.yml \
            .idea/icon.png \
            app/src/main/java/com/companyname/template \
            app/src/test/java/com/companyname/template \

      # Commit modified files
      - name: Commit files
        run: |
          git config --local user.email "action@github.com"
          git config --local user.name "GitHub Action"
          git add .
          git commit -m "Template cleanup"

      # Push changes
      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          branch: main
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
```

1. put that file to *.github/workflows*

[image]

2. to *template-cleanup* put files which should overwrite the default. For example my gradle propeties has group and name fields.
   [image]

It will be rewritten by this part of code

```
 GROUP="com.companyname.$SAFE_NAME"
```

and moved to root by this

```
cp -R app/src/main/java/com/companyname/template/* app/src/main/java/${GROUP//.//}/
```